# Jest test promise resolution and event loop tick

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jestjs

I have a failing Jest test case for code where I'm using promises. It looks like the resolution of the promise is happening after the test has completed, meaning I can't check that my promise resolution code has been executed.

It feels like I need to make the event loop tick so the promise is resolved and the resolution code is executed, but haven't found anything that can do that in Jest.

Here's a sample case. The code to be tested:

```
const Client = require('SomeClient');

module.exports.init = () => {
  Client.load().then(() => {
    console.log('load resolved');

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('load setTimeout fired, retrying init');
      module.exports.init();
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

Test code:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

const mockLoad = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve());

jest.mock('SomeClient', () => {
  return {
    load: mockLoad
  };
}, { virtual: true });

const promiseTest = require('./PromiseTest');

describe('SomeClient Promise Test', () => {
  it('retries init after 10 secs', () => {
    promiseTest.init();

    expect(mockLoad).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // <-- FAILS - setTimeout has not been called

    jest.runAllTimers();

    expect(mockLoad).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

The `expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` assertion fails (`setTimeout` has not been called at all), I think because the promise has not yet been resolved.

Am I doing something wrong here? Can I cause the event loop to tick inside the test?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To tick the event loop inside your test, you should make it asynchronous.
A nice workaround was suggested on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157#issuecomment-279171856).

Having `flushPromises` as suggested there

```
function flushPromises() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}
```

your test will look like

```
describe('SomeClient Promise Test', () => {
  it('retries init after 10 secs', () => {
    promiseTest.init();
    expect(mockLoad).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
    // notice return so jest knows that the test is asynchronous
    return flushPromises()
      .then(() => {
        expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        jest.runAllTimers();

        expect(mockLoad).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
      });
   });
});
```

Or the same using `async/await`:

```
describe('SomeClient Promise Test', () => {
  it('retries init after 10 secs', async () => {
    promiseTest.init();
    expect(mockLoad).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    await flushPromises();
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    jest.runAllTimers();

    expect(mockLoad).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Great! Also works very well in my React + Mobx setup.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why our React setup was different but Sergey's answer nearly got us there.

We needed these two bits in our test:

```
export function flushPromises(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise(jest.requireActual("timers").setImmediate);
}
```

```
await flushPromises();
```

Comment: The difference stems not from your React setup but most likely because you are currently using a newer version of Jest than the one used in the accepted answer. In newer versions of Jest timers are by default faked and so `setImmediate` is undefined unless you use the `requireActual` call.